# How to use HTML code within Javascript script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript if statement, and if it's true I want to run the following HTML code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com" />
```

You may notice that this is just a redirect, and that I could use a javascript redirect instead. The reason I want to do it with HTML is because HTML redirects and javascript redirects behave differently when opening external applications, which is what I'm doing here.

How can I run this HTML code if the javascript if statement is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `insertAdjacentHTML` appears to work:

```js
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com" />`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just write to the document

```js
document.write('Loading... <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com" />');
```

Or add to the DOM.